# How to get a scrolling background inside image effect with css and js? not sure what to call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So essentially what I am looking to do is have a `section` that has a solid background at some point on my page, and at the top of that a pair of sunglasses that as you begin to scroll, the reflection of the sunglasses changes from a few different images, as well as some text changes below the sunglasses to match each change in the sunglasses. Then once the final image is scrolled through, you reach a new `section` with different information. I am not entirely sure what this effect is called or how to achieve it, though I am guessing it will require a significant amount of jquery.

An existing website that demonstrates the effect I am trying to achieve is     https://software.dakno.com/ with the phone effect in the second area down the page. (I do not own this site nor am I affiliated with the owners). I used chrome developer tools to figure out how it is working, but didn't get too far.

The site that I am working on is  http://zack2171.github.io . This is an example site I am using to practice css and web design. The second section is where I am trying to get this effect to work. If someone could help me out a bit and give me some pointers, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at the sites source code and sources and see, what they used.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, your definitely looking towards a mixture of jQuery and css. Most of your time will be dedicated towards the scroll position and at what pixel (Scroll distance) is covered to showing your images/text. I would start to align your image that you want in a position that is either fixed or absolute, to give you a better adjustment. Then start to play around with [jQuery's Scroll Position](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). My personal approach would be to to detect the distance scrolled and after reaching those milestones (Half a page / 3/4 of a page) you would use jQuery to verify the position and then display those extra materials you want to show. I hope this kind of let you onto a good starting path.

Quick example, scroll down within the script below and check the console it logs!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 console.log($(window).scrollTop());
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color:#333;
  height:5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great place to start! I think I will use a combination of this and a set of images that I will make in gimp. I will make a sunglasses image with each reflection I plan to use and use jquery to transition between them as the user scrolls.

Comment: Awesome to hear that! Make sure you select an answer so that this post can be concluded. Take care!